# How to cleanly display multiple hash tables within Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I am working on a Powershell script for my company that will give us a quick look into certain devices that are offline.  I am still very new with Powershell and have been teaching myself how to create scripts and use APIs to gather information.  I am getting this data from a REST api.  I can filter out the offline devices but I cannot cleaning display these devices.  What it similarly looks like currently:

```
PS C:\> $Status

     @{*Information*}
     @{*Information*}
     @{*Information*}
     @{*Information*}....etc.
```

Inside of these hash tables have things like name, status, etc. and all have the same type of information.

I am wondering if there is someway to pull out all of this data and into a table (such as when you run Format-Table).  I have look at documentation for hours and have tried things like $Status.name or $Status.status, Select-Object, and more.

Please let me know if there is documentation that shows how to do this so I can save it for future use, another post that has the answer, or if I did not provide enough information on this.

Thank you.

Edit:  A sample of the full script and the output I was given:

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = 
[Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12

$api_key = '*LONGKEY*'

$api = @{

    "endpoint" = 'https://url.com'

        }

$header = @{

    "For-API-KEY" = $api_key
    "Content-Type" = 'application/json'

           }

    $api.url = 'url/deviceStatuses/'
    $uri = $api.endpoint + $api.url
    $Networks = Invoke-RestMethod -Method GET -Uri $uri -Headers $header

    $Status = $Networks | Select-String -Pattern 'offline'

    $Status
```

Output:

```
    PS C:\> $Status

     @{*Information*}
     @{*Information*}
     @{*Information*}
     @{*Information*}....etc.
```

This script does give me all the information I need, it's just hard to read it all.

Also, the below information is stored in the $Networks (the information shows both online and offline) which I was able to pull the "offline" status from:

```
name                  : 
serial                : 
mac                   : 
publicIp              : 
networkId             : 
status                : online
lastReportedAt        : 
usingCellularFailover : 
wan1Ip                : 
wan2Ip                :
```

Comment: Are you sure `$status` contains hashtables? What does `$status |Get-Member` tell you (it will group output by typename at the top)?

Comment: I thought I had posted those sooner.  I am not entirely sure I guess.  When I run that, I get some things like: Equals (name), method, bool equals(System.object obj).  I will have to read more about the Get-Member command and see what I am missing.  Thank you.

Comment: At the top it will say `TypeName: [some type name]` <- which type name does it show?

Comment: TypeName: Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo

Comment: Ahh, so they're the output from `Select-String`! Please show us the actual call to `Select-String` and a sample input then

Comment: Ah yes, I guess I didn't know if that mattered or not.  I will get a sample over of the full script that I am working on.  It does have all the information I want, just very hard to read.